# Best Solution for redirects if you have to move templates / URL structure

Tags: redirects

If you have to change your url-structure (and therefore in ee-templates) from let's say «opinion/detail/url_title» to «blog/article/url_title» — What's the best solution (EE-functionality, htaccess-stuff or something else) to redirect a visitor to the new url so users clicking on old links get redirected to the corresponding entry-template with the new tempalte-group/template structure?

for example:

`domain.com/opinion/detail/My-Entry` get's automaticly redirected to `domain.com/blog/article/My-Entry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've actually changed the template_group/template structure in EE and you just want to catch old requests and ensure they go to the new location then I'd always look to keep it top-level with .htaccess for this.

First of all ensure that the mod_rewrite module is enabled and the rewrite engine is enabled:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Then using the RedirectMatch (for pattern matching rather than direct file matching) we create a permanent redirect (301) from the old URL schema to the new one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /opinion/detail(.*) http://domain.com/blog/article/$1
```

Provided your new template structure in EE reflects the new schema that should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not opposed to an add-on, I used [Detour Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/detour-pro) on a site with many many URL reroutes and loved it. You can use wildcards with it to save time as well.

Comment: I hope it's a «one time thing», so a Add-On may be a little 'to much' — but thx for the pointer to Detour ;-)

Comment: Saved time is valuable :) Otherwise you might look into adding an htaccess rewrite that does what you're looking for (not my expertise though).